# Creating video from image using FFMPEG

Tags: java, javascript, video, ffmpeg

I am creating video editing application using JavaScript, ffmpeg and java. Using FFMPEG i have created extract n frame of video, than using canvas.toDataUrl I am replacing new image with existing image frame rate and everything has taken care, but when I use these image to create video, FFMPEG never include newly created PNG image.

code to save png image from HTML5 canvas

```
Base64 decoder = new Base64();
    byte[] pic = decoder.decodeBase64(request.getParameter("pic"));
    String frameCount = request.getParameter("frame");
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(pic);
    BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);
    String outdir = "output\\"+frameCount;
    //Random rand = new Random();
    File file = new File(outdir);
    if(file.isFile()){
        if(file.delete()){
            File writefile = new File(outdir);
            ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "png", file);
        }
    }
```

Code for creating image from video

```
String filePath = "D:\\temp\\some.mpg";
    String outdir = "output";
    File file = new File(outdir);
    file.mkdirs();
    Map<String, String> m = System.getenv();

    /*
     * String command[] =
     * {"D:\\ffmpeg-win32-static\\bin\\ffmpeg","-i",filePath
     * ,"-r 30","-f","image2",outdir,"\\user%03d.jpg"};
     * 
     * ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command); pb.start();
     */
    String commands = "D:\\ffmpeg-win32-static\\bin\\ffmpeg -i " + filePath
            + " -r 30  -f image2 " + outdir + "\\image%05d.png";
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
```

code for creating video from image

```
String filePath = "output";
    File fileP = new File(filePath);
    String commands = "D:\\ffmpeg-win32-static\\bin\\ffmpeg -f image2 -i "
            + fileP + "\\image%5d.png " + fileP + "\\video.mp4";
    System.out.println(commands);
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
    System.out.println(fileP.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Does changing image%5d.png to image%05d.png in your code for creating video from image make any difference?

Comment: uer1559108 It worked, can you explain me how you come to know this. I have not noticed that. Well thank you very much i was struggle from couple of hours

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks i got answer

Comment: @yashprit see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared the creation to be image%05d.png and using it ias image%5d.png. So there is one zero less in the name. That's it!

Comment: but when i saw image name was very 00000i.png without extra bit anyways solution is working fine

Comment: The name is correct in the file created. It was wrong in the program part where you were using it.